# How can I hide a non-cancelable dialog from recent tasks?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

In my app I have an activity which displays a non-cancelable alert dialog. I want to hide it from the recent tasks. But when I press the button to show the current recent tasks, the activity is listed there.

So my question is: Why is my activity visible in the list although I have specified `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in my manifest? And how can I fix it?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".AlertDialogActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
</activity>
```

**AlertDialogActivity.java**

```
public class AlertDialogActivity extends Activity {

    public AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    private AlertDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Test").setMessage("This is a test.").setCancelable(false);
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have another Activity in your manifest? I believe that android:excludeFromRecents works only if the Activity is the root activity of the task.... android:excludeFromRecents hides the task (and not the activity)... so, it is applicable only for the root activity... Try to insert there just for test

Comment: A broadcast receiver starts a service which starts my activity.. so it's actually the root activity (although it's not the launcher activity)

Comment: You could try specifying `android:taskAffinity=""` in your `<activity>` declaration in the manifest. This will ensure that this dialog-themed-activity gets launched into a separate task (not the same one as the rest of your application).

Comment: It didn't work, but thanks